# iOS App distribuition for thirdies out of Apple Store

Tags: ios, itunes

I'm developing an app that is supposed to be distributed outside Apple Store. I've read the documentation about app distribution and don't got so clear to me how can I distribute to my specific client... I know I can generate the IPA file, but it is just for testing, right?

What I really need is: get the devices from my client, install the app on those devices for him...

I don't think I need the Enterprise Developer Program, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning to distribute huge amount of users you need an enterprise account. Regular developer account has an option to add device for testing and development up to 100 device.
If you want your app to be tested on clients device first you need to add device UDID onto your developer portal and generate provisioning profile for Ad-Hoc distribution and sign your app with this profile then you can upload it to diawi and send diawi link to your client.
you may watch following tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVO0tIHmQTg

Comment: Thanks a lot! The video was very helpful as well!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TestFlight](https://www.testflightapp.com/) for this. Its easy to use , optional and easy to integrate its SDK and is free for your mentioned usage.
You have to add the UDID of the iPad devices in the dev certificate and upload the app to testflight.

By integrating the SDK you can use multiple other functionalities support as well, like:

```
Sessions
Symbolicated Crash Reports  
Production Crashes
Checkpoints
Remote Logging
In-App Updates
In-App Feedback
```

EDIT: you will be in need of UDIDs of the iPad devices only if you are not using Enterprise developer program.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The ad hoc concept in iOS is a bit confusing... Some people say it is for testing, but I can use it for distribuition also, right? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, You can use that for distribution as well. Apple do not care if you are testing iti or distributing it independently! The point to note is provisioning profile will get expired after 6 months and you have to recreate a app and share that again. In regular developer account you can add upto 100 UDIDs, and you can edit/update this list when you renew your developer your developer account i.e yearly cleaning of UDIDs can be performed!